# .NET Portability analyser tool reports as not compatible for Array.Reverse() API in net standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have created a .NET core 2.0 project and added the below code

```
  public static void Main()
   {
      int nMonths = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(DateTime.Now.Year);
      int[][] months = new int[nMonths][];

      Array.Reverse(months);

      }
   }
```

output from portability analyser

[image]

[image]

complete code is [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netstandard-2.0#system-array-reverse(system-array))

When i ran the Portability analyser tool to check the compatibility with .Net standard 2.0 ,tool gives report as not compatible for Array.Reverse(months); i.e. Jagged array example which is given in Microsoft net standard-2.0 API documentation. since in my current .net core 2.0 project i have used byte[] for some requirement and portability analyser tool report gives as not compatible with .NET standard 2.0 compatibility , i am confused about the result from Portability analyser and the Microsoft API document.

With the below changes, the .NET portability analyser doesn't give any issues

```
private static readonly byte[] beginTime = { 0x01, 0x9e, 0xba, 0xda, 0xd3, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x50 };
 Array dataArray = beginTime;
 Array.Reverse(dataArray);
 beginTime =(byte[])dataArray;
```

Comment: "tool gives report as not compatible" - what's the *precise* message? It would also help if you'd reduce the code to a minimal example, with appropriate formatting - I suspect 95% of this code isn't required to reproduce the problem. (As an aside, I'd also strongly recommend the use of braces for all loop bodies, even when there's only a single statement.)

Comment: It warns about the generic overload `Array.Reverse<T>` not being available in .NET Standard 2.0, which is correct. Only the non-generic `Array.Reverse` is available. But if your project is .NET Core 2, why are you analyzing .NET Standard 2.0 compatibility in the first place? If you build your library targeting .NET Standard 2.0, the correct (available) overload should be picked. If you're *not* building a library, compatibility with .NET Standard is irrelevant to begin with (your Core app needs the Core runtime).

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert ,  Currently i am working on a existing project which is already built in net core 2.0 as a library and now i am running portability analyser to check the existing library compatibility with .NET standard 2.0, 
when i gone through Microsoft API documentation(.NET standard 2.0), they have given the example with Jagged Array for .NEt standard 2.0 , is it correct ?

Comment: If you mean [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netstandard-2.0#system-array-reverse(system-array)), it's specifically using the non-generic overload of the method. If you build your project explicitly as .NET Standard 2.0, the compiler will pick this overload and the portability analyzer should remain quiet. It's arguably a bug/shortcoming that the analyzer can't see this will happen in advance, but presumably it's only using the compiled IL to do the analysis.

Comment: It will definitely work in .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: Thank you so much for the information @JeroenMostert . so if i change my current project  TargetFramework as <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework> , will the compiler will pick all the required overloads automatically ?

Comment: In the specific case of `Array.Reverse` it will, but there may well be other methods that are simply not available in .NET Standard 2.0 and have no alternative overloads either. You should discover this easily enough when compilation fails, though.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert , One last doubt ,  i was modified the .Split() API since it was also found in portability analyser as warning and was modified from Split('\r') to Split(new char[] { '\r' }) , but without any modification i am able to build the code by keeping target framework .NET standard 2.0 , does this also same like  compiler will pick this overload while building the library.

Comment: That *shouldn't* work, since Standard 2.0 has no `String.Split` overload that accepts a single `string` (that was added only in Standard 2.1). It's been a long time since I've built libraries myself targeting .NET Standard, though.